# Make <input> (and enclosing <div>) automatically as wide as content

Tags: html, css

If I have

```
<div><input></input></div>
```

how can I make the width of both the `input` and the containing `div` automatically as wide as the text value currently presented. In particular, I want the box to grow and shrink when the user edits the input.

Can I do is in pure CSS? Do I have to listen for events and update the style? How? (Note: the font in this case is mono-spaced, so probably that makes it easier, although I'm interested in a general solution).

Comment: Not sure why people down voted it, seems interesting to me.

Comment: I believe that it would be impossible for pure CSS, so, I will sit here and wait for superman to come

Comment: If you allowed javascript, this post might be able to solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript

Comment: @SruitA.Suk - yes JavaScript (Scala.js) is allowed. I am trying now with `onkeypress`, but it seems that in the event handler `input.value` is still the old one before adding or deleting the most recent character, so this sucks. I'll check out the linked question.

Comment: @0__ You should listen to `input` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an `input` event listener, which will run whenever the value changes.

And in that listener, update `input`'s [`size` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-size-attribute).

If the font is monospaced, it should work as desired.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function() {
  this.size = this.value.length || 1;
});
```

```css
input { font-family: monospace; }
```

```html
<input size="1" />
```

Answer (score 9):

A Pure CSS solution that might help you:

you can fake the`input` by using `span` then make it [`contenteditable="true"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable) which is widely supported, see [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=contenteditable)

```css
span {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: monospace
}
```

```html
<span contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</span>
```

Comment: Adding `display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap` may be a good idea to make the `span` behave more like an `input`.